# How to Get Notification When Checkin is done in TFS

Tags: tfs, sdk

Whenever someone checks in code to TFS, I want to receive a notification. Is there some way to do it using the API?

Further, I want to get the details of the checkin, like files impacted/change types.

Comment: I don't want email notification that comes out of the box. Question is about the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is how the default email notification works. You can subscribe to an event with bissubscribe, which can send an email or a SOAP notification.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx) for details, including more info on how to write a SOAP service that will deal with the event.

Comment: The link is broken, and it's not clear which issue/article it was going to.

Comment: This is a 7 year old answer, so is not relevant to current versions of TFS. I suggest searching for "TFS email alert" for more info relevant to your version. Note that TFS has a rich and easy to use API and command line tools, so it's now really easy to control TFS from external apps.